# C# Hive DB Connection sample with ODBC Driver using Kerberos Authentication

Tags: c#, odbc, kerberos, hivedb

I have challenge in setting up ODBC connectivity with Hive DB having Kerberos authentication.

Any sample using ODBC driver connection string/ODBC DSN dialog would be greatly helpful

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

See detail setting in pictures with text description for Data Source Name (DSN) in ODBC (with setting of Kerberos and SSL).:

1. DNS source HiveTest [HiveTest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkEJh.png)

- I created Data Source Name: 'HiveTest'

2. DSN, HiveTest detail setting [HiveTest detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygkFo.png)

- Hive Server Type: Hive Server 2
- Service Discovery Mode: No Service Discovery
- Host name: bdp-head01-xxxx.prod (based on installation your solution)
- Port: 10000 (as default for Hive)
- Database: default (as default)
- Authentication/Mechanism: Kerberos
- Authentication/Realm: VN.HW.xxx.PROD (based on content in your keytab file)
- Authentication/Host FQDN: _HOST (default accepted value)
- Authentication/Service Name: hive
- Thrift transport: SASL

3. DSN, HiveTest with SSL detail [SSL for HiveTest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3917H.png)

- SSL/Enable SSL: True
- SSL/Trusted Certificates: xxx.pem (path to your PEM file)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).